# Picking and creating new lists of values, in multiple ranges, from a list of float values

Tags: python, list, numpy, integer, range

I have generated a list of 150 mass values. I need to pick from this list values between 0.2-0.5, 0.5-1.2, etc., and then find the median and range for these parts of the list, but every function I try requires integer items and range limits. Are there equivalents for floats? I tried `range()` and `np.where` among others.

Comment: What specifically have you tried? Please read about creating a [mcve]

Comment: For example, yoiu say you already have the values generated. So have you tried implementing `np.random.choice()`?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
from random import random 
from statistics import median
masses    = [ random()*10 for _ in range(150) ]
intervals = [ (0.2,0.5),(0.5,1.2) ]
for (low,high) in intervals:
   inRange = [ mass for mass in masses if mass >= low and mass < high ]
   print("(",low,",",high,") count=",len(inRange),"median=",median(inRange), "range=", min(inRange),"-",max(inRange))
```